# Round to next largest integer in Julia?

Tags: julia, numerical-methods, scientific-computing

If I have some number in Julia like **1.1**, is there any function/way to round this Float64 to the next largest integer? For example, what function/method could round 1.1 to **2**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ceil` is probably the preferred method here, but just for completeness, you can pass in a `RoundUp` `RoundingMode` to `round()` and get the nearest larger integer as a float too:

```
julia> round(1.1, RoundUp)
2.0
```

You can also search for other `RoundingMode`s by searching for it in help:

```
help?> RoundingMode
search: RoundingMode

  RoundingMode

  A type used for controlling the rounding mode of floating point operations (via rounding/setrounding functions), or as optional arguments for rounding
  to the nearest integer (via the round function).

  Currently supported rounding modes are:

    •  RoundNearest (default)

    •  RoundNearestTiesAway

    •  RoundNearestTiesUp

    •  RoundToZero

    •  RoundFromZero (BigFloat only)

    •  RoundUp

    •  RoundDown
```

Comment: Interestingly, `ceil(Int, 2)` works whereas `round(Int, 2, RoundUp)` gives  an error.

Comment: `round(Int, 2, RoundUp)` gives an error as you can't round an Integer. The second argument has to be a float: `round(Int, 2.2, RoundUp)` gives 3 correctly.

Comment: Agreed. If you want to write a function that works generically on either ints or floats, then you want `ceil(Int, x)` rather than `round(Int, x, RoundUp)`. It's shorter too.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you want smallest integer greater or equal than your value. In this case use:

```
julia> ceil(Int, 1.1)
2
```